# int with atoi() calculated value is always 0

Tags: c, equation, atoi

I am creating a program that will calculate first degree equations. My issue is that, because an equation will include characters and operands, I need to store date on a string and then pass them to integers via `atoi()`. Yet, the answer value never changes from 0 (set value). Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char equation[10];

    scanf("%s", equation);

    int length = strlen(equation);


    char operands[7];
    int op_index[7];
    int op_amount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(equation[i] == '*' || equation[i] == '/' || equation[i] == '+' || equation[i] == '-'){
            operands[op_amount] = equation[i];
            op_index[op_amount] = i;
            op_amount++;
        }
    }

    char nums1[3];
    char nums2[3];
    int i = op_index[0] - 1;
    int j = 3;

    int ans = 0;

    while(isdigit(equation[i]) != 0){
        nums1[j] = equation[i];

        j--;
        i--;
    }

    i = op_index[0] + 1;
    j = 0;

    while(isdigit(equation[i]) != 0){
        nums2[j] = equation[i];

        j++;
        i++;
    }

    if(operands[0] == '*'){
        ans = atoi(nums1) * atoi(nums2);
    }
    else if(operands[0] == '/'){
        ans = atoi(nums1) / atoi(nums2);
    }
    else if(operands[0] == '+'){
        ans = atoi(nums1) + atoi(nums2);
    }
    else if(operands[0] == '-'){
        ans = atoi(nums1) - atoi(nums2);
    }

    printf("ans = %d", ans);
}
```

Comment: What is the input you expect? I assume something like `+ 5 10`. If I use that input your program has a buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/5f69s6qfa You might consider stepping through the code line by line in a debugger to verify it is doing what you expect. Even if the loop to set `nums1` and `nums2` was not going out of bounds neither of those strings would be properly 0 terminated.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I expect something in the terms of `x = 22*2` or the opposite

Comment: Like Ninja said, there needs to be a zero at the end of nums1 and nums2, so you should do something like nums1[last_character_position+1] = '\0'; Use the debugger to check the values of nums*.

Comment: For that input how would `if(equation[0] == '*')` or the other if statements ever be true? `scanf` won't read the whole line anyway, it'll stop at the first whitespace. You probably want to use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are right. I will edit it now...

Comment: Why are you copying the data?  You really shouldn't use `atoi` at all, but suppose `equation` is "12 * 5".  In that case, set `char *op = equation + 3` and `char *a = equation + 5`.  Then return `atoi(equation) * atoi(a)`.

Comment: Also let me add that your method of walking backwards (and forwards) from the operator positions to read the operands on either side seems a bit prone to error/crash. An experienced programmer would probably read everything in order and push it onto some kind of stack for later processing.

Comment: I'll recommend again that you start at the top of your program with a debugger and step line by line to see how it works. Here's the simplest example of why it never would because the method of reading the input doesn't do what you think it does. https://godbolt.org/z/sjKW4WfWj

Comment: @RetiredNinja ok, I will make sure to do so. It is getting late here. If I have further questions or I think I do something wrong on debugging, I will comment again tommorow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note `atoi()` has *zero* error checking and will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` silently returning `0` without any indication an error occurred. Use `strtol()` for full error reporting, or at least `sscanf()` to get a *succeed/fail* indication from the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard.  Or, rather you're making the computer work too hard.  You don't need (or want) to "store date on a string".  You do not need to copy that data around. `atoi` is a broken tool (undefined behavior if the input cannot be represented by an integer), but it is able to mostly do what you want.  Instead of copying the data around, just pass it the first character of the string you are interested in.  The following code does not handle invalid data very well (ie, the string "5 + + + 10" will be treated the same as "5 + 0" and "1foo +3x" is the same as "1+3"), but adding the logic to validate the input is left as an exercise for the reader.  (hint: validating the input is a lot easier if you use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char equation[1024];
    int ans;

    if( 1 != scanf("%1023[^\n]", equation) ){
        fprintf(stderr, "No data avaialable\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *operator = equation + strcspn(equation, "*/+-");;
    char *operand = operator + 1;
    switch( *operator ){
    case '*': ans = atoi(equation) * atoi(operand); break;
    case '/': ans = atoi(equation) / atoi(operand); break;
    case '+': ans = atoi(equation) + atoi(operand); break;
    case '-': ans = atoi(equation) - atoi(operand); break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "No operator found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ans = %d\n", ans);
    if( fflush(stdout) ){
        perror("stdout");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `scanf` is absolutely the wrong way to get input here, and it would make more sense to take the argument as a command line parameter.  If you do read from the input stream, it would make more sense to use `fgets`.  But I keep `scanf` here to demonstrate two thing: you must use a width modifier on `%s` and `%[` conversions to prevent buffer overflow, and you should always check the return value.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. You also made me learn some new functions, that I didn't even know existed (strcspn, strtoll). Eh well I am a begginer, so not much of a surprise in there, Thanks for everything!